# MinGW: undefined reference to all GLFW function calls

Tags: g++, cmake, mingw

MinGW seems to be having problems with finding my GLFW libraries although it can find my header file just fine. The location of my files are as follows:

Header: `C:\MinGW\include\GLFW\glfw3.h`

Library: `C:\MinGW\lib\glfw3dll.a`,`C:\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a`

DLLs: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glfw3.dll`

I'm using Code::Blocks with MinGW-gcc/g++ as the compiler but the command-line equivalent would be something like this:

```
   mingw32-g++ -Wall -o tutorial01 tutorial01.cpp -lOpenGL32 -lglu32 -lglfw3
```

The compiler then complains that it can't find any GLFW functions, even though they're listed in the header file:

```
undefined reference to `glfwInit'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0'
undefined reference to `glfwSetInputMode'
undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIzMr4L.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've also tried including the DLLs and the libs in their 32-bit equivalent folders but that did not fix anything either.

**Update:** Here is my `nm` output. I believe it does contain `glfwInit` unless I'm reading this incorrectly:

```
nm -D .\libglfw3.a
clipboard.c.obj: File format not recognized
context.c.obj: File format not recognized
gamma.c.obj: File format not recognized
init.c.obj: File format not recognized
input.c.obj: File format not recognized
joystick.c.obj: File format not recognized
monitor.c.obj: File format not recognized
time.c.obj: File format not recognized
window.c.obj: File format not recognized
win32_clipboard.c.obj: File format not recognized
win32_gamma.c.obj: File format not recognized
win32_init.c.obj: File format not recognized
win32_joystick.c.obj: File format not recognized
win32_monitor.c.obj: File format not recognized
win32_time.c.obj: File format not recognized
win32_window.c.obj: File format not recognized
wgl_context.c.obj: File format not recognized
```

Comment: I don't think glfwInit is defined in libglfw3. Did you try to see what functions this library file exports by using `nm`?

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, I think it does. I'll update the OP as the output of `nm` is too long for this comment.

Comment: Try `nm foo.a | grep -i glfwinit`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting a very similar issue.

Comment: I figured out my issue: I needed to use glfw3.dll and _only_ glfw3.dll, not libglfw.a or glfwdll.a.